# Convert HTML Megamenu to Yii CMenu zii Widget

Tags: yii, megamenu, cmenu

I just started working with Yii, and I am having some trouble converting my HTML Megamenu to Yii. Basically my html is something like this:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="some_class">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
                <div class="megamenu">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="#" class="overview">Child 1</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col1">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

Adapting this to CMenu widget is proving more difficult than I thouht...especially for e starter like me. I can come up with the classes and lists, but how do I put the Divs within the CMenu Widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your own widget. [Creating widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget) is not harder than creating controllers.

Start from something simple, to see how it plays. Lets try something, this is quick example, does not handle recursion, but could be fine:

```
class MyMenu extends CWidget
{
    public $items = [];
    public function init()
    {
       // Possibli do something with items
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->render('menu', ['items' => $this->items]);
    }
}
```

In views/menu.php:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="some_class">
              <?php foreach($items as $item):?>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><?=$item['title'];?></a>
                <div class="megamenu">

                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="#" class="overview"><?= $item['overview'];?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col1">
                            <ul>
                                         <?php foreach($item['items'] as $row):?>
                                <li><a href="#"><?= $row['title'];?></a></li>
                                          <?php endforeach;?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
                <?php endforeach;?>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then use it in your ccontorller view

```
<?php
$this->widget('path.to.MyMenu', [
    'items' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Foo',
            'overview' => 'Some overview',
            'items' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Bar'
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'Baz'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
?>
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Not tested, just to show idea, might work or not.